# Flutter: Keyboard Size issue building the app

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, build

I am using `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` property in a project to move the `TextField` when the keyboard appeard. When I build the app in debug mode, everything is perfect. However, when another member of the project tries the code, the keyboard height is 0, so the `TextField` does not move up.

We are using git, so all of our codes are the same. Only the files that are included in .gitignore are different. We are using the same flutter versions. To detect the problem I took his complete project folder. When I run his project in my computer, the keyboard did not move as in his computer. So I replaced some of the folders with mines. I realized that **build folder** causes this issue, because when I replace it with mine keyboard problem is gone.

However, when I send my build folder to him, he cannot run the app because the build folder includes some paths in my computer. I am not informed about the build folder. Which files could be the reason for this?

These are my folders into the build folder:

" url_launcher_android"
" webview_flutter_android"
" a05e2a8f25836254c1198f936fbda38e.cache.dill.track.dill"
" last_build_run.json"
" 50567115943de73e877f3f5e89588c53"
" app"
" connectivity_plus"
" facebook_app_events"
" firebase_analytics"
" firebase_auth"
" firebase_core"
" firebase_messaging"
" flutter_keyboard_visibility"
" flutter_local_notifications"
" flutter_native_image"
" flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle"
" geocoding_android"
" google_maps_flutter_android"
" image_picker_android"
" in_app_review"
" integration_test"
" kotlin"
" path_provider_android"
" permission_handler_android"
" sqflite"